# KDE5 Digital clock widget show a different time, than the configured

Tags: linux, kde, clock

I'm using KDE 5 over Arch Linux, and the digital clock widget show a different time than the configured for kde. The widget can be configured to show a different time changing the timezone for it. But I specificly configured the timezone using the same for the rest of the OS.

Another info, the other widgets show that are using the timezone that I had specified, but again they are showing other time, different from the system and incredibly, different than the digital clock widget.

I'd tried changing the timezone for the widget but it doesn't appear to be any difference. It looks like when I try with another timezone, the widget doesn't change it at all.

In the next image you can see the widget in the bottom right corner and the date at the console.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoNHF.png

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What do you get when you hover your mouse over the clock widget?  Do you get one time or more than one?  Does it tell you the time zone?